# Uncountable union of $E_i$'s such that $\forall x\in E_i, \lim_{r\to 0}\frac {\mu(E_i \cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))} = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $\Bbb R^n$. Consider the family $\mathcal F = \{ E_i : i \in I \}$ for some uncountable index set $I$, where each $E_i$ is $\mu$-measurable and has the property that
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac {\mu(E_i \cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))} = 1
$$
for all $x\in E_i$.

> How do we show that the union $E=\bigcup_{i\in I} E_i$ is $\mu$-measurable?

I know that the function $f_i(x) = \limsup_{r\to 0}\frac {\mu(E_i \cap B_r(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))}$ is measurable but I'm not sure if this is relevant or not.

Comment: By $\mu$-measurable, do you mean measurable with respect to the completion of Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ with respect to $\mu$?

Comment: I'd expect so. If it can be proved that $E$ is Borel measurable that'd be great, though I don't know if that's possible or not.

Comment: Is there any nice characterization of sets $E$ with this property? It is easy to check that open sets have this property. Maybe all sets with this property are, in a certain sense, equivalent to open sets?

Comment: @gerw I also noticed that open sets have the aforementioned property but didn't manage to get very far in actually showing that it's a necessary condition. I read somewhere about characterization of Lebesgue measurable sets using the density of its points and points in its complement but couldn't find a reference if similar thing holds for any arbitrary Radon measure.

Comment: Did you mean to say that the limit is $1$ for *all* $x \in E_i$ or only for *almost all* $x \in E_i$? The first is kind of unnatural, since for any measure absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue this condition doesn't hold for most families.

Comment: @pitariver I really meant for all $x\in E_i$, not just almost all.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to work with the outer measure $\mu^*$ associated to $\mu$. The sets $E_i$ also have the above property w.r.t. $\mu^*$ and, by monotonicity, $E$ has this property, as well. Maybe this is enough to prove the measurability of $E$, e.g., by Carathéodory's criterion.